# Windows Phone 8.1 peer to peer secure sockets (HTTPS)

Tags: c#, sockets, https, windows-phone-8.1, p2p

We have a peer-to-peer app on Windows Phone 8.1. The communication happens as HTTP using underlying StreamSocekts.

We want to switch to HTTPS.

Are there any built-in or 3rd party libraries available which supports creating a HTTPS socket/server?

We tried [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/), but not sure where to start with